# Which (numerical) equations should have solutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, number-theory

This is a question about thinking about/feeling/understanding math, so perhaps it should be tagged as a community wiki. Yet, that's about differences between algebra and analysis, so maybe it does indeed have value. It definitely does for me.

I had a particular way of learning how to solve equations, which may be similar to others here, but just a recap. If you don't want to read my motivation and clarification, feel free to jump to **The Question** part below.

- in the early school we've learnt about the addition of integers and we had to solve equations of a kind $a + X = b$ where all numbers are integers. Solving them essentially constituted to guessing what an $X$ should be. At that time we were also taught about some equations not having solutions, for example when $b < a$
- we were then taught about negative integers, which first helped finding $X$ through a formula, and also suddently all equations of the form above started having a solution. *Both of this I liked a lot*
- after adding rational numbers into the picture everything became even better, now each equation of a more general kind $a + cX = b$ had a solution, which was given by a formula
- next step was to learn about square roots and irrational numbers, quadratic equations, where again we had a formula for a solution and a simple characterization for when does the solution exist

All this development seemed to me as natural, adding elegance with each step. As an example, the only reason why $a + X = b$ might not have had solution at the first stage is was our lack of knowlege as school students. Somewhere here I made a choice that I preferred math to language classes, since in the latter grammar had *rules*, but they came with exceptions and worked in some cases only. Math instead had *laws* that worked always. Math was precise and reliable, grammar was handwavy, no matter whether native language or English and French that I also had to learn.

Around same time I've started going to math olypmiads and related courses, where we might have had an equation which was to be solved in integer $X$. I felt disgusted with the fact that for such equations there would have been methods that would only work in some cases, and there was no "elegant" criterion of when an integer solution to such an equation would exist. It felt more like grammar of a natural language than math. It felt like I was asked to solve something with one of my hands tied to one of my legs for no apparent reason. It felt like all the way I went from $a + X = b$ to quadratic equations was for nothing and I had to start guessing again.

So I've declared I never want to have anything related to math olympiads and number theory in particular. I was asked to do a project on p-adic numbers and Pelle equation, which I dumped after a couple of months. I wanted to go to uni and learn more of what I called *continuous math* and forget about those discrete artifacts that I had to deal with in school. The former seemed natural and elegant to me, the latter being artificial and invented for reasons that I was never told about.

Imagine my relief when in the university my first classes were analysis, where starting from basic set theory

- we would use limits to formally prove intermediate value theorem.

Combined with the binary search that provided me with the most elegant way of solving equations one could dream of (from my point of view). You use some limit-based analysis to determine the range for max and min of the function, with that you can show existence of a solution, and if someone needs to know its numerical form (those engineers, you know) they would use a computer program that will give an approximate solution in no time. Why would anyone care for an analytic formula for the roots of quintic? Analytic formulas are such artificial things, be that for roots or antiderivatives. They may happen to exist or not to for reasons of pure luck. My precise thoughts back then.

So my understanding became: we can guarantee existence of a solution for a numerical equation, being a zero of a continuous function, due to continuty of the argument space. That is, availability of the intermediate value theorem, which I now know from topology does hold for connected spaces. The only reason we may not have a solution for equation is when the lhs is outside the range of the function in the rhs. Elegant and natural. Applies to polynomial functions in particular.

I've never had a class in abstract algebra, and even though I knew of finite fields, I did not fully understand that they actually provide an example of a set which is not connected (rather totally disconnected) and yet every polynomial equation there has a solution. From what I understand one does not even need any topology on those fields to show the existence of solutions. With that I feel that there's much more naturality in concepts of number theory that I thought of, and it's a rather orderly area if I just adjust the point from which I look at it.

**The Question:** how can I relate two seemingly completely different ways of the existence of solution for every polynomial: connected spaces and finite (naturally discrete) fields?

Comment: I was just told that no finite field is algebraically closed. So I guess number theory does not stand a chance after all :) I leave a question as it is for now though, appealing to the Cunningham's law

Comment: If I skip to the Question Part , I see a **Single line** which is not very clear. I think , adding more Detail there might make it clear !